# Adding aggregated counts as extra dataframe rows

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, rbind, split-apply-combine

I have a data frame with the letters of the English alphabet and their frequency. Now it would be nice to also know the frequency of the vowels and the consonants and the total number of occurrences - and since I want to plot all of this information, I need it to be in one data frame.

So I often find myself in a situation like this:

```
df <- data.frame(letter = letters, freq = sample(1:100, length(letters)))

df_vowels <- data.frame(letter = "vowels", freq = sum(df[df$letter %in% c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"), ]$freq))
df_consonants <- data.frame(letter = "consonants", freq = sum(df[!df$letter %in% c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"), ]$freq))
df_totals <- data.frame(letter = "totals", freq = sum(df$freq))

df <- rbind(df, df_vowels, df_consonants, df_totals)
```

Am I doing this the right way or is there a more elegant solution for this?

**Looks like my description was terribly confusing:**

Basically, I want to add new categories (rows) to the data frame. In this very simple example, it's simply summarized data.

(For time series plots I'm using the aggregate function.)

[image]

Comment: In your example dataset, there is only a single element for each letter.  So, why do you need aggregate

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I will fix this immediately.

Comment: Your example still has only one row for each letter.  You can check the example in my post.

Comment: The expected result you showed may not be necessary for the plot.  If you have provided more info about the plot, it may be helpful.

Comment: So, you need to group by 'letters' to get the `sum`.  It is a totally different question now.

Comment: Kludging extra rows onto a df just to get things nice for ggplot tends to be a bad idea. See my updated example for how to dynamically use dplyr to append/rbind the two summary rows then ggplot plot the resulting df directly, without overwriting the df.

Comment: I seriously didn't mean to waste your time. I'm sorry I led you into a wrong direction.

Comment: It's okay.  I was trying in a different direction as the `aggregate` step was confusing

Comment: Third update of my answer. Works. Quite elegant if I say so myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: here's a pretty elegant answer to the third version of your question:

```
df <- data.frame(letter = letters, freq = sample(1:100, length(letters)),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)

df = df %>% group_by(letter) %>% summarize(freq = sum(freq))

df.tots = df %>% group_by(is_vowel = letter %in% c('a','e','i','o','u')) %>%
                 summarize(freq=sum(freq))

# Now we just rbind your three summary rows onto the df, then pipe it into your ggplot  
df %>%
  rbind(c('vowels',     df.tots[df.tots$is_vowel==T,]$freq)) %>%
  rbind(c('consonants', df.tots[df.tots$is_vowel==F,]$freq)) %>%
  rbind(c('total',      sum(df.tots$freq)))                  %>%
  ggplot( ... your_ggplot_command_goes_here ...)

  #qplot(data=..., x=letter, y=freq, stat='identity', geom='histogram')
  # To keep your x-axis in order, i.e. our summary rows at bottom,
  # you have to explicitly set order of factor levels:
  # df$letter = factor(df$letter, levels=df$letter)
```

[image: Voila!]

Notes:

1. We needed `data.frame(... stringsAsFactors=F)` so we could later append
   the rows 'vowels', 'consonants', 'total' because those wouldn't occur
   in the factor levels of 'letters'
2. Note that dplyr group_by(is_vowel = ...) allows us to simultaneously insert a new column (`mutate`), then split on that expression (`group_by`), all in one compact line. Neat. Never knew could do that.
3. You should be able to get `bind_rows` working at the end, I couldn't.

---

EDIT: second version. You were saying you want to do an aggregation so we take it each letter has >1 record in df. You seem to be just splitting your df into vowels and consonants, then merging again, so I don't see that new colunms are necessary, other than `is_vowel`. One way is with dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
#  I don't see why you don't just overwrite df here with df2, the df of totals...
df2 = df %>% group_by(letter) %>% summarize(freq = sum(freq))
   letter     freq
1       a      150
2       b       33
3       c       54
4       d      258
5       e      285
6       f      300
7       g      198
8       h       27
9       i       36
10      j      189
..    ...      ...

# Now add a logical column, so we can split on it when aggregating
# df or df2 ....
df$is_vowel = df$letter %in% c('a','e','i','o','u')

# Then your total vowels are:
df %>% filter(is_vowel==T) %>% summarize(freq = sum(freq))
     freq
      312
# ... and total consonants ...
df %>% filter(is_vowel==F) %>% summarize(freq = sum(freq))
     freq
     1011
```

here's another way, a one-liner if you want to avoid dplyr:

```
split(df, df$letter %in% c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u") )
```

By the way, you can form the list(/set) of consonants more easily by just subtracting vowels from all letters:

```
setdiff(letters, c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"))
# "b" "c" "d" "f" "g" "h" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

Comment: Anyway this gives you the idea, please update your example if you meant something different.

Comment: I think I meant something different. Please see my update.

Comment: Third update. Not doing any more for you :) Dynamically creating an object then piping into ggplot with dplyr's `%>%` is pretty elegant. You could wrap a function around this.

Comment: I think you've earned the right to be sarcastic. :-) Seriously, thanks a lot!! I didn't know about piping in R.

Comment: Sadly, the piping is messed up with the crappy necessity to set order on the row levels `df$letter = factor(df$letter, levels=df$letter)`

Comment: Oops, if you look closely, the y-axis values on that 'histogram' are not in numerical order, they're factor order... sigh... you can take it from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82395/discussion-between-not-a-number-and-smci).

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 v2 <- with(df, tapply(freq, c('consonants', 'vowels')[letter %in% 
              v1+1L], FUN=sum))

 df1 <- rbind(df, data.frame(letter=c(names(v2),"Total"), 
            freq=c(v2, sum(v2)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df1, aes(x=letter, y=freq)) +
                  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(letter= sample(letters,200, replace=TRUE),
 freq = sample(1:100, 200, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
v1 <- c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
```

Comment: FYI `dcast` requires 1.9.5 which is the devel version; only 1.9.4 is available on CRAN currently

Comment: @smci Instructions to install the devel version are [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: Yes, just letting people know otherwise they'll see `Error: object 'dcast' not found`

Comment: @smci Thanks for the comment.  Yes, I added that info in the post